# i am not able to figure out exact meaning of this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

**When you are looking like this**, I feel happy/I dont care(/anything).

What's the meaning of "*When you are looking like this*"

I couldn't make out exact literal meaning.

Comment: It would be easier for us to figur out its exact literal meaning, If you provide a context. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: @yubrajsharma:im asking in general

Comment: This isn't a standard phrasing. That's why knowing where you found it is valuable. It sounds like Indian English to me.

Answer (score 3):

"To look like" there refers to the person's outward appearance, and  "this" refers to what the speaker sees while speaking. So the phrase could be (woodenly) paraphrased  "I find it delightful when you appear as you do now".

It is a very general reference to the outward appearance.  It could be that the person looks happy and rested, elegant or unadorned, dressed in mountain-climbing gear or dressed for a swim, in business attire or wearing a superhero costume. We don't know without context.

Comment: okay. but couldn't it mean that when that person is looking at speaker (like this) in this way, he feels happy?

Comment: No, not as stated. At least one thing would change, possibly two. The statement would include **at me**, and **this** would probably change to **that**. *When you're looking at me like that, I feel happy*.

Comment: I agree with@ TRomano

Comment: And we probably wouldn't use the continuous: *When you look at me like that, I feel happy.*